# Finding another occurrence of a result, using Python, urllib

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

How do I find another occurrence of `print(text)`? I mean, how do I repeat this until there is no more to display?

code:

```
def find():
    import urllib
    url = "https://www.pciconcursos.com.br/"
    f = urllib.urlopen(url)

    page = str(f.read())    

    start = page.find('title=')
    begin_quote = page.find('"', start + 1)
    end_quote = page.find('"', begin_quote+1)
    text = page[begin_quote+1:end_quote]

    print(text)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to find all the 'title=' in the page? As in, run `page.find('title=')` in a loop?

Comment: You're using urllib to request the contents of a page that you then convert to a string (page). From thereon it's just a string operations which you are asking about. It has no longer anything to do with urllib.

Comment: This code will find the first occurrence of 'title=' in the page and then the first string delimited by double quotation marks *somewhere* after that in the page — even after one or more subsequent occurrences of 'title=' in the page. I suspect you want to find one or more instances 'title=' with a delimited string. True?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find():
import urllib
url = "https://www.pciconcursos.com.br/"
f = urllib.urlopen(url)

page = str(f.read())    

start = page.find('title=')
begin_quote = page.find('"', start + 1)
while begin_quote != -1:
    end_quote = page.find('"', begin_quote+1)
    text = page[begin_quote+1:end_quote]

    print(text)
    begin_quote = page.find('"', end_quote+1)
```

Might want to add a check for end_quote == -1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want this information. However, it's easy to obtain with lxml. The xpath expression essentially says look in every element for a title attribute.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get("https://www.pciconcursos.com.br/").text
>>> from lxml import html
>>> tree = html.fromstring(page)
>>> tree.xpath('.//*/@title')
['PCI Concursos', 'PCI Concursos', '2017-10-27T17:00:00-02:00', 'IBGE anuncia Processo Seletivo com 1.152 para o Censo Agropecuário 2017', 'IBGE anuncia Processo Seletivo com 1.152 para o Censo Agropecuário 2017', 'Correios prorroga inscrições do Concurso Público com mais de 80 vagas', 'Correios prorroga inscrições do Concurso Público com mais de 80 vagas', 'Em Carapicuíba - SP, Prefeitura contrata 91 profissionais por meio de Concurso Público', 'Em Carapicuíba - SP, Prefeitura contrata 91 profissionais por meio de Concurso Público', 'HCFMRP - USP seleciona Oficiais Administrativos em Concurso Público', 'HCFMRP - USP seleciona Oficiais Administrativos em Concurso Público', 'Câmara Municipal de Arujá - SP divulga retificação de Concurso Público', 'Câmara Municipal de Arujá - SP divulga retificação de Concurso Público', 'Concursos Públicos do AHM - SP passam por alterações', 'Concursos Públicos do AHM - SP passam por alterações', 'Prefeitura de Mogi das Cruzes - SP retifica apenas um dos dois Concursos Públicos em diferentes áreas', 'Prefeitura de Mogi das Cruzes - SP retifica apenas um dos dois Concursos Públicos em diferentes áreas', 'CRF - SP divulga novo Concurso Público com mais de 700 vagas', 'CRF - SP divulga novo Concurso Público com mais de 700 vagas', 'Abrem na próxima segunda-feira (2) as inscrições para o Concurso Público do Valiprev - SP', 'Abrem na próxima segunda-feira (2) as inscrições para o Concurso Público do Valiprev - SP', 'PM - SP: Edital do Concurso Público com 2.200 vagas foi divulgado', 'PM - SP: Edital do Concurso Público com 2.200 vagas foi divulgado', 'TCE - SP retifica Concurso com 133 vagas e salário de até R$ 12,9 mil', 'TCE - SP retifica Concurso com 133 vagas e salário de até R$ 12,9 mil', 'CRESS - SP abre Concurso Público com oportunidades em várias cidades', 'CRESS - SP abre Concurso Público com oportunidades em várias cidades', 'Corpo de Bombeiros - SP lança Processo Seletivo com 600 vagas', 'Corpo de Bombeiros - SP lança Processo Seletivo com 600 vagas', 'MGS - MG retifica Processo Seletivo novamente', 'MGS - MG retifica Processo Seletivo novamente', 'CEMIG divulga período de inscrições de novo Concurso Público', 'CEMIG divulga período de inscrições de novo Concurso Público', 'PM - MG: Concurso Público com 120 vagas tem edital publicado', 'PM - MG: Concurso Público com 120 vagas tem edital publicado', 'IFNMG retifica Concurso Público com vagas para Técnico-Administrativos', 'IFNMG retifica Concurso Público com vagas para Técnico-Administrativos', 'Codemig - MG anuncia Concurso Público com 14 vagas', 'Codemig - MG anuncia Concurso Público com 14 vagas', 'Câmara de Belo Horizonte - MG retifica edital do Concurso Público', 'Câmara de Belo Horizonte - MG retifica edital do Concurso Público', 'TCE - MG retifica pela primeira vez o Concurso Público com salário de R$ 28,9 mil', 'TCE - MG retifica pela primeira vez o Concurso Público com salário de R$ 28,9 mil', 'UFSM - RS anuncia novo Concurso Público com salários de até R$ 4,1 mil', 'UFSM - RS anuncia novo Concurso Público com salários de até R$ 4,1 mil', 'Polícia Civil - SC divulga dois Concursos Públicos com mais de 390 vagas', 'Polícia Civil - SC divulga dois Concursos Públicos com mais de 390 vagas', 'Core - SC abre Concurso Público com cargos de nível médio', 'Core - SC abre Concurso Público com cargos de nível médio', 'Prefeitura de Criciúma - SC retifica Processo Seletivo com 277 vagas', 'Prefeitura de Criciúma - SC retifica Processo Seletivo com 277 vagas', 'UFSC anuncia retificação de Concurso Público com 45 vagas', 'UFSC anuncia retificação de Concurso Público com 45 vagas', 'Prefeitura de Itajaí - SC abrirá Concurso Público para Guarda Municipal', 'Prefeitura de Itajaí - SC abrirá Concurso Público para Guarda Municipal', 'SEGPLAN - GO anuncia as inscrições do Concurso Público destinado ao Procon', 'SEGPLAN - GO anuncia as inscrições do Concurso Público destinado ao Procon', 'DEMAE - GO anuncia a quarta retificação do Concurso Público com salários de até R$ 6,2 mil', 'DEMAE - GO anuncia a quarta retificação do Concurso Público com salários de até R$ 6,2 mil', 'Câmara de Campo Grande - MS retifica Concurso Público com 70 vagas', 'Câmara de Campo Grande - MS retifica Concurso Público com 70 vagas', 'DPE - AM anuncia Concurso Público com 60 vagas e salário de até R$ 6 mil', 'DPE - AM anuncia Concurso Público com 60 vagas e salário de até R$ 6 mil', 'TRF 5ª Região retifica Concurso Público para Técnicos e Analistas Judiciários', 'TRF 5ª Região retifica Concurso Público para Técnicos e Analistas Judiciários', 'UFBA reabre inscrições para um cargo do Concurso para Técnicos-Administrativos', 'UFBA reabre inscrições para um cargo do Concurso para Técnicos-Administrativos', 'Quatro Processos Seletivos são anunciados pelo ISGH - CE', 'Quatro Processos Seletivos são anunciados pelo ISGH - CE', 'DETRAN - CE divulga Concurso Público com mais de 380 vagas', 'DETRAN - CE divulga Concurso Público com mais de 380 vagas', 'CRC - CE prorroga Concurso Público para Contador Fiscal e Auxiliares Administrativo', 'CRC - CE prorroga Concurso Público para Contador Fiscal e Auxiliares Administrativo', 'PM - MA: Data de inscrição para o Concurso Público com mais de 1,2 mil vagas é anunciada', 'PM - MA: Data de inscrição para o Concurso Público com mais de 1,2 mil vagas é anunciada', 'SEE - PB retifica e prorroga inscrições de Concurso com mil vagas para Professores', 'SEE - PB retifica e prorroga inscrições de Concurso com mil vagas para Professores', 'UEPB republica edital e prorroga inscrições para Concurso Público', 'UEPB republica edital e prorroga inscrições para Concurso Público', 'Prefeitura de João Pessoa - PB prorroga Concurso Público na área de Controle Interno', 'Prefeitura de João Pessoa - PB prorroga Concurso Público na área de Controle Interno', 'DPE - PE reabre inscrições do Concurso Público com 50 vagas para Defensores', 'DPE - PE reabre inscrições do Concurso Público com 50 vagas para Defensores', 'Codern realizará Concurso Público para cargo de Guarda Portuário', 'Codern realizará Concurso Público para cargo de Guarda Portuário']
```